# Spring Activiti verify assignee or candidateGroups before completing task

Tags: java, spring, activiti

I'm working with `Spring Acitviti` to manage workflows for a project. I'm new to Activiti and I'm trying get it to work with custom user base. Following is the sample project that I'm working with

https://github.com/ConsciousObserver/AcitvitySpringTest.git

Currently I'm trying to restrict users who can execute a particular task `taskA` in the process `simple-test-process`.

It seems like when calling `taskService.complete(task.getId())` Activiti is completely ignoring who the task is assigned to. Since there's no security configured in the project yet, and `taskA` is assigned to `Hello World` it should fail as anonymous user is trying to execute it.

**Does activity require us to manually check the `assignee`, `candidateUsers`, `candidateGroups` before executing tasks?**

If not then how do we use indicate to Activiti to let only a particular user complete the task.

Including the relevant code below
**simple-test-process.bpmn diagram**

[image: simple-test-process.bpmn diagram]

**simple-test-process.bpmn**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI"
    xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI"
    typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/test">
    <process id="simple-test-process" name="simple-test-process">
        <startEvent id="startEvent" name="startEvent"></startEvent>
        <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow1" targetRef="initTask" sourceRef="startEvent" />
        <serviceTask id="initTask" name="initTask" activiti:expression="${myService.init(photos)}"></serviceTask>
        <sequenceFlow targetRef="taskA" sourceRef="initTask"></sequenceFlow>
        <userTask id="taskA" name="taskA" activiti:assignee="Hello World" ></userTask>
        <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow2" targetRef="taskB" sourceRef="taskA"></sequenceFlow>
        <userTask id="taskB" name="taskB" activiti:assignee="$INITIATOR"></userTask>
        <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow3" targetRef="endEvent" sourceRef="taskB" />
        <endEvent id="endEvent" name="endEvent"></endEvent>
    </process>
</definitions>
```

**ActivitiTestApplication.java**

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.activiti.engine.IdentityService;
import org.activiti.engine.RuntimeService;
import org.activiti.engine.TaskService;
import org.activiti.engine.identity.Group;
import org.activiti.engine.identity.User;
import org.activiti.engine.runtime.ProcessInstance;
import org.activiti.engine.task.Task;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ActivitiTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ActivitiTestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    InitializingBean usersAndGroupsInitializer(final IdentityService identityService) {

        return () -> {
                Group group = identityService.newGroup("user");
                group.setName("users");
                group.setType("security-role");
                identityService.saveGroup(group);

                User admin = identityService.newUser("admin");
                admin.setPassword("admin");
                identityService.saveUser(admin);
            };
    }
}

@RestController
class ProcessRest {
    @Autowired
    private RuntimeService runtimeService;

    @Autowired
    private TaskService taskService;

    @GetMapping("/start")
    public List<Map<String, String>> start() {
        List<String> photos = Arrays.asList("photo1", "photo2");
        runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("simple-test-process", Collections.singletonMap("photos", photos));

        long runningProcessCount = runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().count();
        List<ProcessInstance> processes = runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().list();

        return processes
                .stream()
                .map(p -> getMap(p.getId(), p.getProcessInstanceId(), p.getProcessDefinitionName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @GetMapping("/getTasks/{processInstanceId}")
    public List<Map<String, String>> getTasks(@PathVariable String processInstanceId) {
        List<Task> tasks = taskService
            .createTaskQuery()
            .processInstanceId(processInstanceId)
            .list();

        return tasks
                .stream()
                .map(t -> getMap(t.getId(), t.getProcessInstanceId(), t.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @GetMapping("/completeTask/{processInstanceId}")
    public Map<String, String> completeNextTask(@PathVariable String processInstanceId) {
        Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery()
                        .processInstanceId(processInstanceId)
                        .singleResult();

        if(task == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No pending task for this processInstance");
        }

        System.out.println("variables: " + task.getProcessVariables());

        taskService.complete(task.getId());

        return getMap(task.getId(), task.getProcessInstanceId(), task.getName());
    }

    public Map<String, String> getMap(String id, String instanceId, String name) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("id", id);
        map.put("processInstanceId", instanceId);
        map.put("name", name);

        return map;
    }
}
@Component
class MyService {
    public void init(List<String> photos) {
        System.out.println("################################### Running Init Task ########################");
        for(String photo: photos) {
            System.out.println("Photo name: " + photo);
        }
    }

    public String processPhoto(List<String> photos) {
        for(String photo: photos) {
            System.out.println("Photo name: " + photo);
        }
        return "processed";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not magic that will do that for you, so you will need to verify these things, like the assignee of the tasks and whatnot.

I am betting you will want something more dynamic than the hardcoded "Hello World", so in order to create something more dynamic, as a simple example, I would change your `/start` endpoint from a `GET` to a `POST` and retrieve the assignee as parameter.

```
@PostMapping("/start")
public List<Map<String, String>> start(String assignee) {
```

And pass a attribute in the `processVariables`

something like:

```
Map<String, Object> variables = Collections.singletonMap("photos", photos);
variables.put("person", assignee);
```

Change your bpmn from `activiti:assignee="Hello World"` to `activiti:assignee=${person}`

And add a `TaskListener` that will verify for each task what assignee a user has.
An example of `TaskListener` you will find [here](https://github.com/ilgrosso/activiti-examples/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/activiti/examples/bpmn/tasklistener/AssigneeAssignment.java)

Comment: Thanks, I don't mind doing it manually just wanted to confirm that I'm not doing it the wrong way. Do I need to do anything extra to make Activiti work with Spring security? I'm not planning to use Activiti REST API, all the processes would be exposed through my custom endpoints, is it sufficient that I protect those endpoints with Spring Security?

Comment: I think you need to extend `org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.UserEntityManager` and writing your spring security related things and connect this with activiti in order for the user data to be the same on both sides. I personally haven't done this in my project, so if you hit a wall in regards to this, I would recommend going to activiti forums and try your luck there.

Comment: @11thdimension I stumbled upon this puppy http://www.baeldung.com/activiti-spring-security.  Might be something that would helo you

Comment: Thanks, I tried to implement that before, I came to the conclusion that since I'm implementing Spring security in my project itself I don't need to override these Activiti specific classes. Those classes merely act as configuration for Spring Security, which as you mentioned (and I verified too) will not be verified automatically by Activity itself.